# How to use fread() to read the entire file in a loop?

Tags: c, fread

I want to transfer a file via a socket in linux system. I know how to use fgetc() and EOF to do so, or first get the length of file. Is there any other option?

Comment: Why do you ask? Do you need the entire file content in memory (why, what kind of content)? On which operating system? Perhaps you want [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)? Please **edit your question** to improve it.

Comment: If it is a text file, `fgets()` is a better option than `fread()`.

Answer (score 4):

Check for the return value of `fread()`. If the return value is not equal to the 3rd parameter passed into `fread()`, either error happens or EOF is reached.

Comment: Note that this differs from the underlying `read(2)` POSIX system call.  `read()` can return less than a full buffer if interrupted, or after a packet from a socket, or after a line on a line-buffered tty, and stuff like that.  `fread()` keeps calling `read` until the buffer is full or it reaches EOF.

Answer (score -2):

Function fread() reads data from the given data stream(4th parameter) to an array pointed in to by a pointer(1st parameter)

```
fread (pointer to the block of memory, size of an element, number of elements, pointer to the input file)
```

fread() reads from where it left off last time and returns the number of elements successfully read. So if u do as below fread() will not go beyond that.

*You have to edit the number of elements according to the input file.

```
// Open input file
FILE *inptr = fopen (infile, "r");
//Check for a valid file
if (inptr == NULL)
{
    fprintf (stderr, "Could notopen %s", infile);
    return 1;
}

// Memory allocation for buffer
int *buffer = malloc(512);

// Read input file
while (fread (&buffer, 1, 512, inptr) == 512)
{
      // DO WHAT YOU NEED HERE
}

// Free memory from buffer
free(buffer);

// close infile
fclose(inptr);

return 0;
```